# How to know which checkbox was selected in a form after using Implode PHP?

Tags: php, forms, post

I built an instant quote calculator which gives a price when the checkboxes are clicked. Some of those checkboxes have the same price.

When I use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function in the `$_POST['package']` variable which has the values of those checkboxes (I send them after to an email), I can't tell which checkbox was selected.

HTML code:

```
<form>
    <p><fieldset id="packages" class="logo_choice">
    <legend>Do you want to register a new website?</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="package[]" id="package_basic" value="15.00">
            <label for="package_basic">Yes <font color="F69B35">($15)</font></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="package[]" id="package_pro" value="0.00">
            <label for="package_pro">No <font color="F69B35">($0)</font></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="package[]" id="package_pro" value="0.00">
            <label for="package_pro">Maybe <font color="F69B35">($0)</font></label>
        </li>

    </ol>
    </fieldset></p>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
$email_message .= (isset($_POST['package'])) ? 
              "Domain: ".implode(" ", $_POST['package'])."\n" : '';
```

The email I receive:

```
Domain: 0.00 15.00 0.00
```

How can I know which one was chosen (i.e. which checkbox was selected)?

Comment: As stated in an answer below, instead consider radio buttons with `name="package"`, which will result in something like `$_REQUEST['package'] = '15.00'`. That said, [if you do not specify the keys, the array gets filled in the order the elements appear in the form](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays). Perhaps it's because you have duplicate `id`s?

Comment: where is your form action and method?

Comment: @asefseferov <form class="tsc_form_contact_light" name="contactform" method="post" action="./Quote/send_form_email.php" method="post">

Comment: @user113215 for some things i use radio, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

You ought to both specify a suitable HTML type, e.g. radio, and set appropriately the names (you have a duplicate ID now):

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="package" id="package_basic" value="15.00">
    <label for="package_basic">Yes <font color="F69B35">($15)</font></label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="package" id="package_pro" value="0.00">
    <label for="package_pro">No <font color="F69B35">($0)</font></label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="package" id="package_maybe" value="0.00">
    <label for="package_maybe">Maybe <font color="F69B35">($0)</font></label>
</li>
```

This will give you `package=<value>` without imploding.

Or you can use an array, but then you can't easily use `implode` since you will only gather the *values*, not where they come from, so you would need a cycle:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="package[basic]" id="package_basic" value="15.00">
    <label for="package_basic">Yes <font color="F69B35">($15)</font></label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="package[pro]" id="package_pro" value="15.00">
    <label for="package_pro">No <font color="F69B35">($0)</font></label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="package[extra]" id="package_extra" value="20.00">
    <label for="package_extra">Maybe <font color="F69B35">($0)</font></label>
</li>

$total = 0;
foreach ($package as $key => $value) {
    $email .= "package {$key} for {$value}<br />\n";
    $total += $value;
}
if ($total > 0) {
    $total = number_format($total, 2);
    $email .= "for a total of {$total}";
}
```

which would give you, say,

```
package basic for 15.00
package extra for 20.00
for a total of 35.00
```

Answer (score 0):

if only 1 can be ticked at anytime , you should be using radio buttons

also if your using checkboxes all 3 values need to be different so you the difference if your going to using an array

Comment: package[] should work. That just means if you check off two of those choices, $_POST['package'] will contain an array with both values

Comment: Thanks, yeah im using radio for some of them, its a very long form this is the first. And it gets very confusing as well

Comment: @TonyArra what would your solution to this? Please